# Best way to sync folder on mobile? (iOS/Android)

Tags: android, ios, svn, directory, synchronization

So I'm having a problem here.

For a project I'm looking for a way to sync a remote folder to my mobile device. Since I'm on my own on this I have not get the manpower to maintain a separate homebrew sync api/library.

So I'm looking for a way to do this:

Things I've tried: setup a subversion repository and update the folder on the mobile device.

This worked very well, but there is no subversion iOS library so I have to find another way.

So I've found openmobster, but this seems to be for enterprises and looks way to large for an app this small (100 users a day or something) and requires a java server to run all the time.

I've found owncloud, a dropbox like cloudsync, with android and ios libraries. I'm thinking about doing it this way, but the libraries are very premature and I still have to do the syncing, new file recognition etc myself. The server-side is a php library so it fits with my other websites on the server.

Other way I maybe want to do this, is just setup a webdav folder and look for a synchronization library for iOS and Android. The problem with this is that there is no single developer making both libraries. Which increases the risk of bugs I think.

So I'm asking for advice, what do you guys think is a good way to go? If there is some sort of subversion iOS library this would do. But I think I should change directions and find a new way to do this. Every other option would be welcome.

Very many thanks in advance, I will buy you a cake!

Comment: What solution did you favour in the end?

Comment: I did choose the owncloud setup, it allowed making a read only account for the app, and an administration panel voor the admin to upload new images etc on the fly. The downside was that there was a huge bug in the library which didnt allow running at all. I'm glad it was opensource so i fixed it myself. The syncing had to be done by myself but that wasn't too difficult. I think it is still more safe than building an REST api myself. It is nice because it's just a webdav running on php. So no serverload while not in use.

Comment: Thanks Barry. So you had to write the iOS code to pull down the files?  And is it the same files for each user? Sounds pretty good. I wish there was a Dropbox alternative without requiring OAuth for each user. And had local desktop folder syncing, and also an iOS SDK. Sounds like you've got quite close to that.

Comment: Hi Tobin, no the library has the ability to sync files. I just had to write code to see if files are new or shouldn't be updated. Implement the dropbox functionality. I setup an admin account and shared a readonly folder to another account which is used in the app. No OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm looking for a way to sync a remote folder to my mobile device.**

FYI :

[This](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite&hl=en) app can do the syncing process between the folder in your mobile storage to remote folder. May be it is useful for you..